# In C#, how do you communicate via Kermit over a serial port?

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication, kermit

I am about to start on a project where I have to communicate with (extract data from) a medical device via serial port. The documentation for the device says that it communicates via the Kermit protocol. It's been 10 years since I even thought about Kermit. 20 Years since I've used it. Are there any libraries for this? If I roll my own, what's involved?

I am developing in .NET 4.0 C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345027/free-modem-serial-communications-library-or-scriptable-app-with-zmodem-kermit)

<strike>I found no traces of a C# Kermit binding, and I believe there are none since the language is pretty young</strike>

A good option <strike>is</strike> may be to choose your favourite C++ implementation and **wrap** it with P/Invoke

[Update]
Probably somebody ungraved Kermit: https://www.adontec.com/super_net_faq.htm